# Downloading File from a URL using PHP script

Tags: php, download

Hi I want to download some 250 files from a URL which are in a sequence. I am almost done with it! Just the Problem is the structure of my URL is:
http://lee.kias.re.kr/~newton/sann/out/201409//SEQUENCE1.prsa

Where id is in a sequence but the file name "SEQUENCE1.psra" has a format "SEQUENCE?.psra".
Is there any way I can specify this format of file in my code? And also there are other files in  folder, but only 1 with ".psra" ext.

```
Code:
<?php
// Source URL pattern
//$sourceURLOriginal = "http://www.somewebsite.com/document{x}.pdf";
 $sourceURLOriginal = " http://lee.kias.re.kr/~newton/sann/out/201409/{x}/**SEQUENCE?.prsa**";
// Destination folder
 $destinationFolder = "C:\\Users\\hp\\Downloads\\SOP\\ppi\\RSAdata";
// Destination file name pattern
 $destinationFileNameOriginal = "doc{x}.txt";
 // Start number
   $start = 7043;
// End number
$end = 7045;
 $n=1;
// From start to end
for ($i=$start; $i<=$end; $i++) {
// Replace source URL parameter with number

    $sourceURL = str_replace("{x}", $i, $sourceURLOriginal);

    // Destination file name
    $destinationFile = $destinationFolder . "\\" . 
    str_replace("{x}", $i, $destinationFileNameOriginal);
// Read from URL, write to file
    file_put_contents($destinationFile, 
    file_get_contents($sourceURL)
    );
// Output progress
echo "File #$i complete\n";
}
?>
```

Its working if I directly specify the URL!

Error:
Warning: file_get_contents( http://lee.kias.re.kr/~newton/sann/out/201409/7043/SEQUENCE?.prsa): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\xampp\htdocs\SOP\download.php on line 37
File #7043 complete

Its making the files but they are empty!

If there is a way in which I can download that whole folder(named with id in sequence) can also work! But how do we download the whole folder in a folder?

Comment: Could you give a few examples of actual source urls, so that I can understand how exactly they are supposed to change as $i goes up?

Comment: I understand the increment... I dont get the "?". Btw, this would be a perfect reason to use sprinf(). `sprintf('http://lee.kias.re.kr/~newton/sann/out/201409/%d/SEQUENCE%d.prsa',$i,$whatever);` Also: There is an extra space at the beginning of `$sourceURLOriginal`. Dont know if you are aware

Comment: actually the main thing I want to ask is The folder with an id like(7056 - 7240) has a file with extension ".rsa" I want only that file no other. The name format of this file is "SEQUENCE?" where "?" says it can be any number! I know we cannot specify like this but dont know the correct way either!

Comment: Two immediate things come to mind. If you have FTP access, that would be fantastic (Im assuming you have explored this option, though). You can use easy functions to get a list of the files in each folder and download them the easy way. No guessing. The second would be: if they have directory indexing (and they do) you can probably slap together something to read the structure that way and figure out the file name. Once you know all the contents, you can choose which files to download

Comment: Also, I browsed through the files a lil bit, each sequence goes up by one. You should be able to use that to increase the sequence number as well

Comment: no its not for every file! I uploaded so that it gives in a sequence but it dependes when it has processed the data! Can you tell me the method for getting the directory listing and selecting one of them

Comment: Yeah im aware of that space. it does not create any issue

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible file_get_contents() function is not working on your server.
Try this code :

```
    function url_get_contents ($Url) {
        if (!function_exists('curl_init')){ 
            die('CURL is not installed!');
        }
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $output;
    }
```

Comment: I tried directly giving the url.. so it was working! o I dont think  this is the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.
I didnt test the whole `file_get_contents`, `file_put_contents` part, but if you say its adding the files (albeit, blank) then I assume it still works here...

Everything else works fine. I left a `var_dump()` in so you can see what the return looks like.

I did what I suggested in my comment. Open the folder, parse the file list, grab the filename you need.
Also, I dont know if you read my original comments, but `$sourceURLOriginal` has an extra space at the beginning, which might have been giving you an issue.

```
<?php

$start=7043;
$end=7045;

$sourceURLOriginal="http://lee.kias.re.kr/~newton/sann/out/201409/";
$destinationFolder='C:\Users\hp\Downloads\SOP\ppi\RSAdata';

for ($i=$start; $i<=$end; $i++) {
    $contents=file_get_contents($sourceURLOriginal.$i);
    preg_match_All("|href=[\"'](.*?)[\"']|",$contents,$hrefs);
    $file_list=array();
    if (empty($hrefs[1])) continue;
    unset($hrefs[1][0],$hrefs[1][1],$hrefs[1][2],$hrefs[1][3],$hrefs[1][4]);
    $file_list=array_values($hrefs[1]);
    var_dump($file_list);

    foreach ($file_list as $index=>$file) {
        if (strpos($file,'prsa')!==false) {
            $needed_file=$index;
            break;
        }
    }

    file_put_contents($destinationFolder.'\doc'.$i.'.txt',
        file_get_contents($sourceURLOriginal.$i.'/'.$file_list[$needed_file])
    );

}
```